# Unable to trigger Firebase Cloud Function to save payment method to existing Stripe customer

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'm new to Swift and Firebase, and I'm trying to use Stripe to save user payment details for future purchases with Firebase Cloud Functions. I'm able to create a new Firebase user which automatically triggers my `createStripeCustomer` Cloud Function, which works perfectly.

But now I'm having trouble saving payment details. To collect payment info, I'm using Stripe's `STPAddCardViewController`. After entering payment details, a paymentMethod is created, which I can see from `addCardViewController(_ didCreatePaymentMethod)`. When I save this to my Firestore, it's triggering the next Cloud Function, `addPaymentMethodDetails`, but it's giving an error.

On my Firestore dashboard it shows that the `addPaymentMethodDetails` "Function execution started", then gives an error saying "userFacingMessage is not defined". The `userFacingMessage` is only mentioned in the catch block, so there must be an issue with how I'm storing the payment details, right? Here's a screenshot of the function log:

[Firestore Functions Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myowO.png)

I'm confused about what exactly I should save to Firestore, and where to save it.

- Do I only save the `paymentMethod.stripeId`, or the entire `paymentMethod` object? Firebase's example code says "When adding the payment method ID...", so I assume only the id needs to be saved to trigger this function. Based on the sample Cloud Function below, it looks like once I save it to this location in Firestore: `document('/stripe_customers/{userId}/payment_methods/{pushId}')`, then the function will be triggered. However, this makes it seem like I need to save the entire object to a document inside the payment_methods collection, but I'm not able to pass an STPPaymentMethod as Document data.

Here's the sample index.js file provided by Firebase that I'm referencing:
https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/stripe/functions/index.js

Below is the Swift code I'm trying to use to write to Firestore, followed by the Cloud Function. I tried passing the `paymentMethod` object to the `addDocument` method, but I'm not sure how to change it from type STPPaymentMethod to [String : Any]

`db.collection("stripe_customers").document(auth.currentUser!.uid).collection("payment_methods").addDocument(data: [String : Any])`

```
/**
 * When adding the payment method ID on the client,
 * this function is triggered to retrieve the payment method details.
 */

  exports.addPaymentMethodDetails = functions.firestore
  .document('/stripe_customers/{userId}/payment_methods/{pushId}')
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    try {
      const paymentMethodId = snap.data().id;
      const paymentMethod = await stripe.paymentMethods.retrieve(
        paymentMethodId
      );
      await snap.ref.set(paymentMethod);
      // Create a new SetupIntent so the customer can add a new method next time.
      const intent = await stripe.setupIntents.create({
        customer: paymentMethod.customer,
      });
      await snap.ref.parent.parent.set(
        {
          setup_secret: intent.client_secret,
        },
        { merge: true }
      );
      return;
    } catch (error) {
      await snap.ref.set({ error: userFacingMessage(error) }, { merge: true });
      await reportError(error, { user: context.params.userId });
    }
  });
```

Any help would really be appreciated. Please let me know if there's any necessary information that I left out.

Comment: If you are using the `STPAddCardViewController`, Stripe should automatically save the payment method to the customer associated with the ephemeral key you passed to the SDK per: https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/basic#ephemeral-key. So there is likely no need to pass the payment method ID back to Firestore. You should be able to retrieve the payment method off the customer in your Cloud Function using: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/list

Comment: When I look at the customer on my Stripe dashboard, they aren't updated with any payment methods. On this page, it says the addCardViewController automatically tokenizes the info, but I don't see anything about it being added to the customer.

https://stripe.dev/stripe-ios/docs/Classes/STPAddCardViewController.html#/c:objc(cs)STPAddCardViewController(py)apiClient

Here's the sample Cloud Functions provided by Firebase that I'm referencing. I don't see any ephemeral key being created

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/stripe/functions/index.js

Comment: Gotcha, the tutorial you're following doesn't look to be creating an ephemeral key. The idea is that you would create an `STPCustomerEphemeralKeyProvider` and use it to initialize a `STPCustomerContext`, which would should tie the `STPPaymentContext` to a customer and save the payment methods automatically. That doesn't look relevant for the integration path you're going with though. We can work with what you have so far. Can you confirm whether or not the `addPaymentMethodDetails` Cloud Function gets called at all? Can you for example log the output of `snap.data()`?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I added console.log(snap.data()); at the top of the try block, but nothing is shown in the debug console. However, my Firestore Log is showing that the function is executing but has an error. I've updated the original question with the error message and a screenshot. Maybe I need to save the entire paymentMethod object instead of just the paymentMethod ID?

Comment: it looks like the true error is getting swallowed up because you haven't defined the `userFacingMessage` function. Could you try adding that somewhere in the Cloud Function: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/stripe/functions/index.js#L200-L207. That at the very least would give you a reasonable error message which should shed more light on the issue.